# How to read values from text file, with row and column data in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

Hi there basically I have a text file that contains many rows and column of numerical data an example can be seen below.

```
21,73,12,73,82,10
17,28,19,21,39,11
17,39,19,21,3,91
12,73,17,32,18,31
31,29,31,92,12,32
28,31,83,21,93,20
```

What I want to be able to do is to read each value separately with the row and column number being identified also.
    ie. row 0 column 2 would be 12

Then to be able to write the row, column and value to a variable. ie = i,j,d

I can read them into an array and split by line, get the column count and row count fine, I just have no idea how I can separate each value individually.

Below is some code that I believe works that was written from pseudocode with "i" and "j" being row and column number, and "b" being the data from the table above relevant to this, which would then loop.

```
i = 0
for a in array:
    j = 0 
    for b in array:
        if b != 0:
            write.code(i,j,b)
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Comment: Learn Python's [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Try: `map(lambda l: map(int, l.split(',')), open('file'))` for fun

Comment: try 'for b in a:' instead of 'for b in array:'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick based on your original code.

```
# using with is the safest way to open files
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    # enumerate allows you to iterate through the list with an index and an object
    for row_index, row in enumerate(file):
        # split allows you to break a string apart with a string key
        for col_index, value in enumerate(row.split(",")):
            #convert value from string to int
            # strip removes spaces newlines and other pesky characters
            b = int(value.strip())
            if b != 0:
                g.add_edge(row_index,col_index, b)
```

If you want to just turn it into an array, you can condense this with list comprehension.

```
with open(file_name, "r") as file:
     my_array = [ [int(value.strip()) for value in row.split(",")] for row in file]
```

Comment: That's brilliant does what I wanted to do when in a seperate .py file for testing, however, I am getting an error that I cannot seem to resolve, here is the traceback if it helps




    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "yes2.py", line 65, in <module>
        g.add_edge(u,v,w)
      File "yes2.py", line 27, in add_edge
        self.adj[u].append(edge) 
KeyError: 0

Comment: That is an issue within your own custom function of which I cannot help you. Try printing all your data up to the `self.adj[u].append(edge)` and evaluate if something is amiss

Comment: also the error states that `u` is value 0 and that there is no indexed item in `self.adj` with that key